# Use Vercel Comments in a preview branch with fixed alias

Tags: next.js, vercel

Im trying to setup Vercel comments with this fixed preview alias. Right now the comments works on the specific build link, but I'd like to be able to comment on my preview alias so my team can do follow up along next commits.

I have production and preview alias for my Vercel project. Let's say my preview alias is `beta.x.com`. If a PR get's merged into `dev` a preview build gets triggered.

I'd like to access my preview alias and see the Vercel Comments.

I've added the Env Variable as mentioned here https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/comments/specialized-usage and also it's turned on in the project settings. Am I missing something or is this something Vercel didn't make available yet?